# Redirect the Chrome extension popup.html page to a URL for Oauth

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth

Is it possible to redirect the popup Html of a chrome extension to a remote URL?

I'm looking into this scenario for the purpose of OAuth. When a user clicks on the "Login with FB" button,

I want the Html page of the chrome extension to redirect to: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}` so that the user is prompted to log in.

Is this the right approach to do authentication in  a Chrome extension anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popups are very.. fragile. They are too easy to close, the user can't use password managers to fill the form etc. They are also very size-constrained. Maybe not the best idea.

You can, instead, use `chrome.windows` to create a login-type window:

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: "YourLoginURL",
  type: "popup",
  focused: true
});
```

---

However, all that is not the "native" way to do OAuth in Chrome extensions.

The native way is to use [`chrome.identity` API,](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) specifically [`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow).

As an added bonus, it allows you to use a virtual `https:` callback URL, which is the most widely supported option, without having to own a domain.