# Stripe redirectToCheckout fails in a Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get a stripe Client-Sided checkout working in my chrome extension. I've been following this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client-subscription

I've tried putting their code into a popup window. It looks like this right now: 
[image]

Here's popup.html (It's a popup as a browser_action in my manifest):

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button
      style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
      id="checkout-button-price_1I4qrHGQOs7it271rCHFzqLQ"
      role="link"
      type="button"
    >
      Checkout
    </button>

    <div id="error-message"></div>

    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's popup.js:

```js
(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51I3tT4GQOs7it271yzphuPAJAVSCfFPbIaVkKg3QC260ECeY5xHrVRhYcUjdyGV8ubVdl29mgwRsPWA3HFG5a6Fq00H6uAO1dz');

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1I4qrHGQOs7it271rCHFzqLQ');
  console.log(document);
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    /*
     * When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
     * them to Checkout.
     */
     console.log("Click!");
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      lineItems: [{price: 'price_1I4qrHGQOs7it271rCHFzqLQ', quantity: 1}],
      mode: 'subscription',
      successUrl: 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/globenewswire-100-results/hehfpofokmibphnefmofemjckioibaaj/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/globenewswire-100-results/hehfpofokmibphnefmofemjckioibaaj/canceled',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.error) {
        /*
         * If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
         * error, display the localized error message to your customer.
         */
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

And here's my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "GlobeNewsWire Infinite Scroll",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "Infinite scroll on GlobeNewsWire",
  "permissions": ["identity", "identity.email"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.globenewswire.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["manage_scroll.js", "auth.js"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com; object-src 'self'",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I'm stuck on step 3 of the tutorial. The stripe.redirectToCheckout call doesn't redirect anywhere (nothing happens). I know it runs because I get a log on Stripe. I've also tested it by simply opening the HTML file and clicking the button (which works).

So I assume there's a problem with how stripe.redirectToCheckout runs in a popup. Has anyone figured out how to do this in an extension? My only goal is to accept payments but I'm trying to avoid any server-side code (hence the tutorial being for a client-side only implementation). Thanks!

edit: I want to mention that there aren't any errors in my console. The only error I get is from the response of my stripe.redirectToCheckout call. result.error.message evaluates to "Failed to redirect to https://checkout.stripe....."

Comment: It might be a protection mechanism of the browser to prevent showing remote arbitrary HTML in the popup of an extension. By the way, it is recommended to paste code as text instead of images. No one that wants to help you will type the code in the images to reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: Ah that's true, mb. I've changed the pictures to code. I think that makes sense (not allowing a redirect in the popup). But then I'm unsure how I can get this working in the extension. I've seen others use redirectToCheckout within their extensions before, but I don't have their full code, so I haven't been able to replicate it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25770235/2738151) mentions the possibility of creating a new window and the fragility of popups.

Comment: If you update your `content_security_policy` to `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://js.stripe.com/v3/; object-src 'self'"` does it work or change the console output?

Comment: @JustinMichael I get the same behavior. Except I now have an error from when I load my extension:

`'content_security_policy': Ignored insecure CSP value "'unsafe-inline'" in directive 'script-src'.`

Comment: I had a chat with a colleague who tried to get Checkout working in a Chrome extension and the best they could do was to get it to work on the config page, not in the popover.  Honestly it's probably a fluke that it works there at all, and I wouldn't recommend counting on it.  You should send people to a page hosted on your server, then redirect to Checkout from there instead.

Comment: Heads up: this may no longer be possible with Manifest v3 since remotely hosted code is prohibited ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/)).